# Plotting function goes wrong when adding new parameter

Tags: r, function, plot, polygon

I'm a beginneR using R Studio with R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet" in Windows 7.

Data I'm using...

```
   > dput(head(data,20))
structure(list(case = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), age = c(37, 42, 44, 40, 26, 29, 42, 26, 
18, 56, 29, 66, 71, 26, 30, 48, 39, 65, 65, 48), bmi = c(25.95, 
29.07, 27.63, 27.4, 25.34, 31.38, 25.08, 28.01, 24.69, 25.06, 
27.68, 23.51, 29.86, 21.72, 25.95, 22.86, 23.53, 21.3, 33.2, 
29.39), ord.bmi = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3), alcohol = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), tobacco = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1), dent.amalgam = c(1, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1), exp.years = c(7, 
9, 9, 5, 2, 10, 15, 5, 1, 40, 10, 50, 50, 1, 12, 22, 22, 30, 
40, 30), mn = c(0, 0, 0, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 2, 1), bn = c(2.5, 5, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 4, 2, 1.5, 
4.5, 4.5, 2.5, 2, 6, 2, 5, 4, 1, 1.5, 7, 1.5), ln = c(0.5, 1.5, 
0, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4.5, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3), 
    pn = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0, 0), cc = c(0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1.5, 4.5, 2, 
    0, 3.5, 2, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 2, 1.5), kr = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 
    0, 0), kl = c(0.5, 2, 0, 1.5, 1.5, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1.5, 
    1.5, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3.5, 4.5, 2)), .Names = c("case", "age", 
"bmi", "ord.bmi", "alcohol", "tobacco", "dent.amalgam", "exp.years", 
"mn", "bn", "ln", "pn", "cc", "kr", "kl"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm plotting two different densities (which I get using `density.a <- lapply(data[which(data$case == 0),], density)` and `density.b <- lapply(data[which(data$case == 1),], density)`), and everything seems to work fine:

```
plot.densities <- function(sample.a, sample.b){  # declaring the function arguments
    for(i in seq(length(sample.a))){  # for every element in the first argument (expected equal lengths)
        plot(range(sample.a[[i]]$x, sample.b[[i]]$x), # generate a plot
             range(sample.a[[i]]$y, sample.b[[i]]$y), 
             xlab = names(sample.a[i]), ylab = "Density", main = paste(names(sample.a[i]), "density plot"))
        lines(sample.a[[i]], col = "red")  # red lines
        lines(sample.b[[i]], col = "green") #green lines
    }
}
```

When I call the function, I get plots like this: 
[image: GOOD (?) PLOT]

Then, if I want to fill the line between the two curves, I add the polygon function and looks like this:

```
filled.plot <- function(sample.a, sample.b){  # declaring the function arguments
    for(i in seq(length(sample.a))){  # for every element in the first argument (expected equal lengths)
        plot(range(sample.a[[i]]$x, sample.b[[i]]$x), # generate a plot
             range(sample.a[[i]]$y, sample.b[[i]]$y), 
             xlab = names(sample.a[i]), ylab = "Density", 
             main = paste(names(sample.a[i])))
        lines(sample.a[[i]], col = "red")  # red lines
        lines(sample.b[[i]], col = "green") #green lines
        polygon(x = c(range(sample.a[[i]]$x, sample.b[[i]]$x), 
                      rev(range(sample.a[[i]]$x, sample.b[[i]]$x))), 
                y = c(range(sample.a[[i]]$y, sample.b[[i]]$y), 
                      rev(range(sample.a[[i]]$x, sample.b[[i]]$x))),
                col = "skyblue")         
    }
}
```

But when I call the `filled.plot` function, I get plots like this:

[image: BAD PLOT]

I'm stuck, and some help would be just fine!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need  `seq()` calls that go between range endpoints (low to high and back). Using the range function only gets you the endpoints. ... and you need to use the density values as the y-vectors. The density construction looks like it could be simplified, too.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post a sample of your data, say 20 rows, by command 'dput(head(data,20))'

Comment: @rnso, just added the data as you said.

Comment: @BondedDust, I tried the `seq()` instead of `range()` but I get `Error in seq.default(sample.a[[i]]$x, sample.b[[i]]$x) : 
  'from' must be of length 1`... I don't get the use the density value as y-vector, I get the density as x and y values(???) vector as Also, could you specify how would you simplify the density construction?     sorry if the answers are obvious

Comment: Show that you have read the help page ?polygon and used the second example as a template.

Comment: @BondedDust It took a while... I replaced the `seq(sample.a[[i]]$x, sample.b[[i]]$x)`because it returned error (`from and to must be of length 1`) with `c()` and it also followed the ?polygon example 2 template. It worked. It coloured all the areas between the two lines.

Comment: I think you are a better programmer for it. Letting `ggplot` do it all for you leaves you completely dependent on what it's developers think you should be doing, not what you want to do. Also look at the coding behind pkg:plotrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with ggplot (I have changed the case value of rows 11:20 to 2):

```
ggplot()+
geom_density(data=testdf[testdf$case==1,], aes(age),fill='red', alpha=0.5)+
geom_density(data=testdf[testdf$case==2,], aes(age), fill='green', alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: use p=ggplot(... ; print(p);readline(prompt="press ENTER for next graph..");  in the loop.